# SQLite database supporting Unicode data

Tags: sqlite

I'm using java swing application which needs unicode string to drag into jtable.Is it possible to store unicode data in SQLITE database? If so,which SQLite does support unicode..I need free sqlite not the premium..

Comment: What *premium* version are you refering to? SQLite is a single open source library

Comment: In fact, SQLite is [in the public domain](https://sqlite.org/copyright.html). You *can* get "Professional Support" and buy ["Proprietary SQLite Extensions"](https://sqlite.org/support.html).

Comment: You should provide some code (full running sample) where you try to write and read data to / from your database. Most likely the problem will be obvious then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQLite always stores text data as Unicode, using the *Unicode* encoding specified when the database was created. The database driver itself takes care to return the data as the Unicode string in the encoding used by your language/platform.

If you have conversion problems, either your application tried to store an ASCII string without converting it to Unicode, or you tried to read one value and force a conversion on it.

SQLite uses a kind of [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), where each *value* is stored using a specific storage class. A column's type specifies the *affinity* or how the value is treated. For example:

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL

There are five storage classes, NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB. TEXT stores string data using the Unicode encoding specified for the database (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

What specific problem are you facing, or is this a general question?

Comment: I want to add some chinese characters in my database..but when i insert into sqlite,it gets changed as '?'.What type of encoding should i use to support the chinese,japanese languages.

Comment: @use: Since you are using Java (which uses UTF-16 encoding for strings), you should make sure, that your SQLite DB is set to use UTF-16 as well. This can be done when [opening a new database](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html), or set by using [`PRAGMA encoding`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding). This is based on the assumption, that your Java library doesn't perform any encoding itself.

Comment: To clarify - any valid ASCII string *is* a valid utf-8 string. It needs no conversion. That is by design. But to be clear, ASCII characters run from code point 0 to code point 127. Any characters beyond that are NOT ASCII. This includes accented characters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite always uses Unicode strings.

Comment: thanks..but does it insert chinese character ? character gets modified as ?

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 doesn't fully support UNICODE. There is a wrapper class called [CppSQLite3](https://github.com/neosmart/CppSQLite) which fully supports UNICODE>

Comment: SQLite **fully** supports storage and retrieval of Unicode strings, encoded as UTF-8, UTF-16LE, or UTF-16BE. The only aspect of Unicode that SQLite does not support is case-insensitive matching of characters. The proposed library doesn't add anything in that department. Could you elaborate?

Comment: There are many issues with SQLite3 and UNICODE and if you need full UNICODE support, you need a wrapper class such as CppSQLite3.

Comment: The OP is asking about **storing** Unicode strings. The question isn't asking about Unicode operations. It's still wildly unclear, what Unicode-related issues you are referring to (*"there are many issues"* is not entirely enlightening), and which ones the proposed library actually tackles. That library looks like a C++ wrapper, without any additional functionality outside of resource management.

Comment: Sqlite of course stores UNICODE strings. That is correct. However, how do you store these strings...  You can use DB Browser for SQLite but programmatically you need APi functions that accept char_t * as opposed to char * strings (or std::wstring), The purpose of CppSqlite3 is to add the missing  sqlite3 lacks to have (on the API level). http://softvoile.com/development/CppSQLite3U/

Comment: Please read the [sqlite_bind_\*](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) reference documentation to learn about the interface, and how it handles text. That should answer the question *"how do you store these strings..."*.