# How to save an emoji into database?

Tags: ios, sqlite, emoji

I've a string which holds this    emoji and I wants to store it into sqlite database, this string is coming from server, the string can be in combinations of, only emojis, emojis + text, and only text. How do I handle and store each string I'll get from the server.

I've already code, to store / retrive the texts from the database and its working fine. But when I got an emoji in texts, its changing the output, and instead of an emoji its showing me some random characters like this, üÜé.

How to handle this case?

Comment: You need to perform Encoding and Decoding using utf-8 on your String properly in order get the emojis in the required format .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397231/4596420)

> SQLite always stores text data as Unicode string.

Previosly I was retriving text like this,

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
```

I changed it to this,

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
```

and its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can send emoji to server in utfstring and for showing emoji in textfield you can change that string into nonlossyasciistringencoding in viewdidload.in this way you can show emoji.