# CSV UTF-8 file insert to table had type mismatch error

Tags: android, excel, sqlite, csv, utf-8

I want to import a csv(comma delimited) file to sqlite. I save csv file in asset folder and then insert in table... I have to save the file as UTF-8 format. 
When I save CSV file without UTF-8 format, my application runs without any problems but when I save the same CSV file in excel and then save in utf-8 format and then to set on asset folder, during insert, I get the following error:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
```

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //db=context.openOrCreateDatabase(sDB_Name,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL(sCreate_Table);
    createDBFromCSV(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + MASKANLOC_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

private void createDBFromCSV(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(maskanFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String column_value[];
        String insert_row = "insert into " + MASKANLOC_TABLE + " (" + COLUMN_ID + "," + COLUMN_LAT + "," + COLUMN_LONG + "," + COLUMN_ADDRESS + "," + COLUMN_CODE + "," + COLUMN_TYPE + "," + COLUMN_UPLOADED + ")" + " values(\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            column_value = line.split(";");
            String setCommand = String.format(insert_row, column_value[0], column_value[1], column_value[2], column_value[3], column_value[4], column_value[5], column_value[6]);
            db.execSQL(setCommand);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for advises

Comment: SQLite in Android stores all the data in Unicode (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19397231/697716), so assuming you read all records correctly, they should be inserted in the database without any problem. I suggest you open the file exported from Excel in a text editor (e.g. Sublime) and make sure the content is correct before putting it into the assets directory. Also put a breakpoint on `column_value = line.split(";");` line and inspect all columns are properly split and there is no issues there. This might help a bit more what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks @m.hashemian. I put breakpoint and i trace my application before, everything is correct and set in correct place but not worked. finally i cant found my problem but i export a xlsx file from excel and then open with openoffice, in openoffice i saved file with csv and utf-8 format and worked in my applilcation..... if anyone have a solution for above problem please send to me. again thanks .