# SQLite database shows question marks (???) instead of these Unicode characters (தமிழ்)

Tags: sqlite, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, db-browser-sqlite

I imported a CSV file containing Unicode into an SQLite database but instead of seeing the text, all that I see are question marks. Like this, "???". The encoding is UTF-8 (I've mentioned below what happened when I tried UTF-16). The SQLite manager I'm using is DB Browser for SQLite.

This is the Unicode that I typed: தமிழ்

Now, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393824/sqlite-database-supporting-unicode-data) answer in Stackoverflow, SQLite stores text data as Unicode. So the fact that my text is Unicode can't be the problem.

The characters I'm trying to use belong the language Tamil. I'm trying to use it with Unicode. According to Wikipedia, encoding for Tamil is called TACE16. It's a 16-bit Unicode based character encoding.

So then I set the encoding as UTF-16 when I imported the CSV file. But the file doesn't even show up in the database after importing when I do that. But it says import is successful.

Then I tried importing the CSV file with UTF-8 encoding as usual. But after importing I right clicked the row header, selected "Set Encoding" and set it to UTF-16. Now it didn't show question marks but it shows something like Chinese characters. This is what it shows now: 㼿㼿.

I tried setting TACE16 while importing. I also tried setting it manually. But it said it's either an incorrect encoding or it is not supported.

Further searching online didn't turn up anything. Could someone tell me how I can fix this issue? Basically, I want this text "தமிழ்" to show in the SQLite database after importing the CSV file which has the text.

Thank you so much. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: A database does not "show" anything; it retrieves data for the program that asks for it, and it is that program's job to display it. This looks like a problem with DB Browser.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @CL., Thanks. It seems the CSV file didn't get saved with the required encoding setting. I created a CSV file with notepad. I made sure to set the encoding as Unicode when I saved it. It worked well. Both in the program an as well as the DB Browser. I've written about it as an answer. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue once but in my case the problem were only on the DB software I used to visualize DB tables. Have you tried to retrieve your data from the database? Are they right when you retrieve them?
Anyways if you tell us what tools are you exactly using for doing what it is impossible to find a solution in your specific case.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the issue was with the csv file. I figured it out after trying out a few things. It seems excel doesn't save the csv file using the encoding that I need. I've written about that as an answer to this question. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out the issue was my csv file. I edited it in excel and I guess excel saved it using another encoding. I'm still not sure what's the exact issue but I'll just write about how I fixed it.

I opened Notepad and typed out the data separated by commas. I saved the file with the extensions csv. Here's the important thing. You have to change the encoding to Unicode. There's a drop down menu just left of the save button. Use that. Here's a link to a youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foG5Ffr6aNE) that shows you how.

Also, you don't need to type everything in a Notepad. It can get tedious.

Type everything out in Google Spreadsheets and export download it as a CVS file. It works. If you have to use Notepad, type the data in excel, concatenate everything in each row with using a formula, and copy paste it into a notepad. Don't forget to add a comma between each cell info using the formula in excel.