# How to store speacial symbols in SQLITE

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, discord.py

This is my table

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    db = sqlite3.connect('Smilewin.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Introduce(
        guild_id TEXT,
        channel_id TEXT,
        boarder TEXT,
        status TEXT
        )
        ''')
```

[image]

I wanted to store anything from a normal text to something like this `☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆`
(basically anything)

When I try to store `☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆ﾟ ゜ﾟ☆`  It is giving an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ardil\Desktop\Desktop app\ANAPAH\Code\ReactV9\Smilewin-env\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\ardil\Desktop\Desktop app\ANAPAH\Code\ReactV9\SmileWinbot.py", line 618, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\ardil\Desktop\Desktop app\ANAPAH\Code\ReactV9\Smilewin-env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\ardil\Desktop\Desktop app\ANAPAH\Code\ReactV9\Smilewin-env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ardil\Desktop\Desktop app\ANAPAH\Code\ReactV9\Smilewin-env\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The code which I use to store that special symbols is:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def setboarder(ctx, *,boarder):
    db = sqlite3.connect('Smilewin.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT boarder FROM Introduce WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone
    if result is None:
        sql = ("INSERT INTO Introduce(guild_id, boarder) VALUES(?,?)")
        val = (ctx.guild.id , boarder)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour= 0x00FFFF,
            title = "ตั้งค่ากรอบเเนะนําตัว",
            description= f"กรอบได้ถูกตั้งเป็น {boarder}"
        )

        message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await message.add_reaction('✅')
    
    elif result is not None:
        sql = ("UPDATE Introduce boarder = ? WHERE guild_id = ?")
        val = (boarder , ctx.guild.id)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour= 0x00FFFF,
            title = "ตั้งค่ากรอบเเนะนําตัว",
            description= f"กรอบได้ถูกอัพเดตเป็น {boarder}"
        )

        message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await message.add_reaction('✅')
        
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    db.commit() 
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

I want to know is it possible to store that kind of data in sqlite. If yes how can I do it please provide some example. thank you so much

Comment: Regarding *is it possible to store that kind of data in sqlite* i suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393824/sqlite-database-supporting-unicode-data

Comment: So yes it is possible right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your update query which may or may not have some bearing on the problem.

`"UPDATE Introduce boarder = ? WHERE guild_id = ?"`

is missing the keyword `SET`. The statement should be:

`"UPDATE Introduce SET boarder = ? WHERE guild_id = ?"`

I don't see how the exception traceback relates to this problem. It also seems unrelated to whether the db can store your unicode strings; it can.

Try fixing this bug and see how you go.

Comment: Oh i have not realize that let me see

Comment: Good. No problem.