# C# utf string conversion, characters which don't display correctly get converted to "unknown character" - how to prevent this?

Tags: c#, string, sqlite, unicode

I've got two strings which are derived from Windows filenames, which contain unicode characters that do not display correctly in Windows (they show just the square box "unknown character" instead of the correct character). However the filenames are valid and these files exist without problems in the operating system, which means I need to be able to deal with them correctly and accurately.

I'm loading the filenames the usual way:

```
string path = @"c:\folder";
foreach (FileInfo file in DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles(path))
{
    string filename = file.FullName;
}
```

but for the purposes of explaining this problem, these are the two filenames I'm having issues with:

```
string filename1 = "\ude18.txt";
string filename2 = "\udca6.txt";
```

Two strings, two filenames with a single unicode character plus an extension, both different. This so far is fine, I can read and write these files no problem, however I need to store these strings in a sqlite db and later retrieve them. Every attempt I make to do so results in both of these characters being changed to the "unknown character", so the original data is lost and I can no longer differentiate the two strings. At first I thought this was an sqlite issue, and I've made sure my db is in UTF16, but it turns out it's the conversion in c# to UTF16 that is causing the problem.

If I ignore sqlite entirely, and simply try to manually convert these strings to UTF16 (or to any other encoding), these characters are converted to the "unknown character" and the original data is lost. If I do this:

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
string filename1 = "\ude18.txt";
string filename2 = "\udca6.txt";
byte[] name1Bytes = enc.GetBytes(filename1);
byte[] name2Bytes = enc.GetBytes(filename2);
```

and I then inspect the bytearrays 'name1Bytes' and 'name2Bytes' they are both identical. and I can see that the unicode character in both cases has been converted to a pair of bytes 253 and 255 - the unknown character. and sure enough when I convert back

```
string newFilename1 = enc.GetString(name1Bytes);
string newFilename2 = enc.GetString(name2Bytes);
```

the orignal unicode character in each case is lost, and replaced with a diamond question mark symbol. I have lost the original filenames altogether.

It seems that these encoding conversions rely on the system font being able to display the characters, and this is a problem as these strings already exist as filenames, and changing the filenames isn't an option. I need to preserve this data somehow when sending it to sqlite, and when it's sent to sqlite it will go through a conversion process to UTF16, and it's this conversion that I need it to survive without losing data.

Comment: Why do you think that they're [valid characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF)?

Comment: If `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` can't get it, then it was probably never loaded correctly in the first place. [SQLite handles Unicode fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393824/sqlite-database-supporting-unicode-data) How are you getting these strings into C#, **please show code.**

Comment: because they already exist as files on the operating system. I didn't name them this way, they already exist this way

Comment: why is there a \ in front of the name?

Comment: they are unicode characters, each character shown in the format \uxxxx

Comment: code that got me these filenames :

`string path = @"c:\path";
foreach(FileInfo file in DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles(path))
{
   string filename = file.Name;
}`

Comment: and yes SQLite handles unicode fine, but in UTF16 or UTF8, and converting these strings to UTF16 or UTF8 in c# results in lost data. the problem is in this conversion, not in sqlite. I can inspect these filename strings in the debugger just fine, I can convert them to chars just fine, but convert to bytes and the data is lost

Comment: Do you get this problem with the Encoder even before you've touched SQLite? If so then either there is something wrong with the way .NET is loading the filenames (I note that [they *are* using Unicode](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/faee0f9f700fa6f3.html)), or more likely they are actually stored on disk like that (as @Damien_The_Unbeliever says, it might be an .unpaired surrogate etc)

Comment: yes that's exactly my point, this problem happens independently of sqlite - I've deliberately not included any sqlite in my code snippets for this reason. these are the filenames I've got. the strings contain these characters, and it all works fine in the standard c# string encoding, I can read and write the files just fine. the problem is encoding the strings to UTF16 or anything else breaks them, and when inserting to sqlite there is a conversion to UTF16 taking place, so what I need is a way to make these characters not get lost when converting

Comment: the app I'm working on is basically a file copy/backup app, so it needs to not care what characters are in the filenames, and it needs to not skip files just because something in the code doesn't like unusual characters

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - that link describes my problem exactly

"Windows allows unpaired surrogates in filenames and other places, which generally means they have to be supported by software in spite of their exclusion from the Unicode standard."

here I have Windows filenames containing these characters, and I need my software to support them, and I need them to survive conversion to UTF16 somehow

Comment: Try to use `Regex.Escape` on the file names.

`var escapedName = Regex.Escape(filename1)`

Comment: probably should have mentioned, this is one of the first things I tried - it ignores these characters completely. I think I'm probably looking for a solution along these lines though!

Comment: Setting `Encoding.EncoderFallback` on a `new UnicodeEncoding` with a delegate that can deal with these characters may be a solution. I suggest if you want to deal with such characters that you store them as byte arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast a `char` to an `int`, you get the numeric value, bypassing the Unicode conversion mechanism:

```
foreach (char ch in filename1)
{
    int i = ch; // 0x0000de18 == 56856 for the first char in filename1
    ... do whatever, e.g., create an int array, store it as base64
}
```

This turns out to work as well, and is perhaps more elegant:

```
foreach (int ch in filename1)
{
    ...
}
```

So perhaps something like this:

```
string Encode(string raw)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2 * raw.Length];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (int ch in raw)
    {
        bytes[i++] = (byte)(ch & 0xff);
        bytes[i++] = (byte)(ch >> 8);
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}

string Decode(string encoded)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; ++i)
    {
        chars[i] = (char)(bytes[i * 2] | (bytes[i * 2 + 1] << 8));
    }

    return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: this appears to work perfectly, thank you! exactly the solution I was after!